# router.put not working, app.put working fine

Tags: javascript

I did a route for edit and update. `router.get()` for edit is working fine, but `router.put()` for update is not working. I is working in my main `app.js`, though.

I am using method override

```
//edit (working)
router.get('/userList/:id/edit', function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser){
    res.render('admin/userList/edit', {user: foundUser})
    console.log(req.params.id)
    // console.log(req.body.id)
  });  
});

//update  (not working)
router.put('/userList/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user, function(err, updatedUser) {
    if(err) {
      res.redirect('back');
      req.flash("error", "Coś poszło nie tak!");
    } else {
      res.redirect('back');
      req.flash("success", "User został zmodyfikowany!");
    }
  })
})

//update in main app.js (working)
app.put('/userList/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user)
  })            
})
```

form:

```
<form action="/userList/<%= user._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user[username]" value="<%= user.username %>" >
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by `is not working`. We'd like to to help you, but we need more context - we can't see through your eyes

Comment: i am getting this "Cannot PUT /userList/5b38bcc90973a450cad2ad72". When i use only router.put('/', ...) then callback is working, otherwise not, probably something is wrong with path router.put('/userLIst/:id), dont know, thank u